# Wrapping text in a JavaFX TableView editable TextFieldTableCell

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

My TableView consists of several columns and wraps the text with the following cellfactory:

```
private void setWrapCellFactory(TableColumn<CustomObject, String> table) {
    table.setCellFactory(tablecol -> {
        TableCell<CustomObject, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
        Text text = new Text();
        cell.setGraphic(text);
        text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(cell.widthProperty());
        text.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());
        return cell;
    });
}
```

This works perfectly for showing uneditable text.

The last column has to be editable and could span across several rows (not TableView rows). To prevent the ellips I would like to wrap the new edited text.

After hours of trying I still can't seem to get it working. I have the following code to edit my cell and a non-working attempt to wrap it.

Non-working method to wrap my edited text:

```
private void setWrapCellFactoryEditable(TableColumn<CustomObject, String> table) {
    table.setCellFactory(tablecol -> {
        TableCell<CustomObject, String> cell = new TextFieldTableCell<>(new DefaultStringConverter());
        Text text = new Text();
        text.setText(text.toString());
        text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(cell.widthProperty());
        return cell;
    });
}
```

The following code is the column setup:

```
feedbackCol.setCellValueFactory(ev -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(ev.getValue().getLastFeedback()));
    setWrapCellFactoryEditable(feedbackCol);
    feedbackCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<CustomObject, String> ev) -> {
        int id = ((CustomObject) ev.getTableView().getItems().get(
                ev.getTablePosition().getRow())).getId();
        dc.addTempFeedback(id, ev.getNewValue());
    });
```

For the regular non-editable text I'm using a `TableCell`, for editable text I'm using a `TextFieldTableCell`. I don't know why the wrapping isn't working with editable cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own class extending `TextFieldTableCell`. It should override `cancelEdit()` and `updateItem()` methods to change cell graphic to `Text` component (equal to one you used for non-editable cells) when editing is finished.

```
public class WrappingTextFieldTableCell<S> extends TextFieldTableCell<S, String> {

    private final Text cellText;

    public WrappingTextFieldTableCell() {
        super(new DefaultStringConverter());
        this.cellText = createText();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setGraphic(cellText);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!isEmpty() && !isEditing()) {
            setGraphic(cellText);
        }
    }

    private Text createText() {
        Text text = new Text();
        text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        text.textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static class TextAreaTableCell<S> extends TextFieldTableCell<S, String> {    
    private final IntFunction<ObservableValue<Boolean>> editableExtractor;
    private TextArea textArea;
    private final Text cellText;

    public TextAreaTableCell(IntFunction<ObservableValue<Boolean>> editableExtractor, StringConverter<String> converter) {
        super(converter);
        this.editableExtractor = editableExtractor;
        this.cellText = createText();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateIndex(int i) {
        super.updateIndex(i);
        if (i == -1)  {
            editableProperty().unbind();
        } else {
            editableProperty().bind(editableExtractor.apply(i));
        }
    }

    public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S, String>, TableCell<S, String>> forTableColumn(IntFunction<ObservableValue<Boolean>> editableExtractor) {
        return forTableColumn(editableExtractor, new DefaultStringConverter());
    }

    public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S, String>, TableCell<S, String>> forTableColumn(IntFunction<ObservableValue<Boolean>> editableExtractor, 
            final StringConverter<String> converter) {
        return list -> new TextAreaTableCell<>(editableExtractor, converter);
    }

    private void createTextArea() {
        textArea = new TextArea(getString());
        textArea.setWrapText(true);
        textArea.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textArea.focusedProperty().addListener(
                (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
                    if (!newValue) {
                        commitEdit((String)textArea.getText());
                    }
                });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : (String) getItem();
    }




    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!editableProperty().get()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextArea();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textArea);
            textArea.selectAll();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        if (!editableProperty().get()) {
            return;
        }
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(cellText);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        if (!editableProperty().get()) {
            return;
        }
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText((String)item);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textArea != null) {
                    textArea.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textArea);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(cellText);
            }
        }
    }


     private Text createText() {
        Text text = new Text();
        text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        text.textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
        return text;
    }

}
```

and use:

```
colDiagnose.setCellFactory(TextAreaTableCell.forTableColumn(i -> Bindings.valueAt(editable, i).isEqualTo(Boolean.TRUE)));
```

Comment: White this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include some explanation of how this code answers the question, to provide context to future readers. A code block by itself is not immediately useful to those who might come across the same issue later on.