# JavaFX: How wrap text in tablecell without a listener?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecell

Currently I use a listener to wrap text on a tablecell but that causes a little delay when load/reload data table. Are there any other way to do this without use a listener?

```
TableColumn<Peticion, Void> colObs = new TableColumn<>("Observaciones");               
        colObs.setPrefWidth(200);
        colObs.getStyleClass().add("columData");
        colObs.setCellFactory(col->{            
            TableCell<Peticion, Void> cell = new TableCell<Peticion, Void>(){
                    public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            Peticion p = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());  

                            Label l = new Label(p.getObservaciones());
                            l.setWrapText(true);
                            VBox box = new VBox(l);
                            l.heightProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue)-> {
                                    box.setPrefHeight(newValue.doubleValue()+7);
                                    Platform.runLater(()->this.getTableRow().requestLayout());
                            });
                            super.setGraphic(box);
                            }
                    }       
            };
            return cell;
        });
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Note that it's nearly always very suboptimal to interfere with layouts by setXXSize (XX = pref/min/max).
 Unrelated: don't create new nodes on every call to updateItem (that happens often!) Instead create them once at instantiation time and configure.

Comment: also unrelated: no need to call super.setGraphic (it's final, such it is the same as setGraphic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping text in a JavaFX TableView editable TextFieldTableCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440067/wrapping-text-in-a-javafx-tableview-editable-textfieldtablecell)

Comment: @Zephyr,  these allows to do a refresh data on the table and it continues wrapping the text on a HBox inside the cell?