# JavaFX Wrapping an editable TextFieldTableCell

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to get a TableView TextFieldTableCell to be both wrapping the text and adjusting the cell height and also be editable at the same time.

So i'm able to make it wrapped or editable, but not at the same time.

I have been following this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440067/wrapping-text-in-a-javafx-tableview-editable-textfieldtablecell) and trying about a 100 different permutations and possibilities. I'm sure it is possible, but i'm reaching full fustration quickly. So any help would be highly appreciated!

I'm using SceneBuilder and importing the handles. MainFX.fxml: -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="wrappingEditableCellProject.Controller">
<children>
  <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
     <children>
        <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
          <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="id" prefWidth="75.0" text="id" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="name" prefWidth="75.0" text="name" />
          </columns>
        </TableView>
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
</children>
</StackPane>
```

My Main class:

```
package wrappingEditableCellProject;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainFX.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("mainFx");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 600));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

My data entry class:

```
package wrappingEditableCellProject;

public class TableEntry {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public TableEntry (int id, String name){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

My Controller class:

```
package wrappingEditableCellProject;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

public class Controller {

    @FXML TableView<TableEntry> tableView;
    @FXML TableColumn<TableEntry, Integer> id;
    @FXML TableColumn<TableEntry, String> name;

    private ObservableList<TableEntry> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public void initialize(){
        // Set editable
        tableView.setEditable(true);

        // Configure columns
        id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        id.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<TableEntry, Integer>forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
        id.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER-LEFT;");
        id.setEditable(false);
        id.setSortable(false);

        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        name.setCellFactory(WrappingTextFieldTableCell.<TableEntry>forTableColumn());
        name.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER-LEFT;");
        name.setSortable(false);
        name.setOnEditCommit(evt -> {
            System.out.println("Edit comitted");
            evt.getRowValue().setName(evt.getNewValue());
        });

        TableColumn[] tableColumns = {id,name};
        tableView.getColumns().clear();
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(tableColumns);

        // add data to the table
        dataList.clear();
        dataList.add(new TableEntry(1, "Steve Upperton Stevenson"));
        dataList.add(new TableEntry(2, "Peter May Parker"));
        dataList.add(new TableEntry(3, "Tony Stark the machinist"));
        dataList.add(new TableEntry(4, "Pepper Pots the CEO of Stark industies"));

        FilteredList<TableEntry> dataFiltered = new FilteredList<>(dataList, b -> true);
        SortedList<TableEntry> dataSorted = new SortedList<>(dataFiltered);
        dataSorted.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());
        tableView.setItems(dataSorted);

    }

}
```

Here is my custom cell class WrappingTextFieldTableCell:

```
package wrappingEditableCellProject;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class WrappingTextFieldTableCell<S> extends TextFieldTableCell<S, String> {

    private final Text cellText;

    public WrappingTextFieldTableCell() {
        super(new DefaultStringConverter());
        setPrefHeight(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        this.cellText = createText();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setGraphic(cellText);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!isEmpty() && !isEditing()) {
            setGraphic(cellText);
        }
    }

    private Text createText() {
        Text text = new Text();
        text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        text.textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
        return text;
    }
}
```

This solution allows me to edit the cell(I know there are easier ways for this), but the wrapping is not taking.

As mentioned i have tried 100 different ways to approach this challenge, but i think this would be the easiest to relate to for any assistance.

Thanks for any support!

Comment: @kleopatra should be done now, do you know a solution to my challenge?

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly (what you are showing are mere snippets, not even compilable - whom do you expect to fill out the periods ;)

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for your input, I have now made a completely compilable and runnable example of my challenge. Maybe you can assist with the challenge?